# XPath using position() in a nested context does not produce the desired result

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

Using XPath 1, I'm trying to return a node set of `item`s within a certain range which have distinct `dept_number` values within them. The range which these items are in is dynamic. The document is structured like the following:

```xml
<data>
    <items>
        <item>
            <dept_number>1</dept_number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dept_number>1</dept_number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dept_number>2</dept_number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dept_number>2</dept_number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dept_number>3</dept_number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dept_number>4</dept_number>
        </item>
        <item>
            <dept_number>4</dept_number>
        </item>
    </items>
</data>
```

The best way I could think of doing this is like the following:

```xml
/data/items/item[not(dept_number = preceding-sibling::item[position() > $min]/dept_number) and position() > $min and position() <= $max]/dept_number
```

where `$min` is the lower bound of the range and `$max` is the upper bound. This is not working. For instance, if I use

```xml
/data/items/*[name() = 'item' and not(dept_number = preceding-sibling::*[position() > 1]/dept_number) and position() > 1 and position() <= 5]/dept_number
```

it returns

```xml
<dept_number>1</dept_number>
<dept_number>2</dept_number>
<dept_number>2</dept_number>
<dept_number>3</dept_number>
```

which is not a set of distinct values. What I would expect is

```xml
<dept_number>1</dept_number>
<dept_number>2</dept_number>
<dept_number>3</dept_number>
```

I believe the issue is with using `position()` within a nested context (i.e. `/data/items/item[... preceding-sibling::item[position() > $min] ...]`. It seems to be using the result you would get from `position()` when used in the outer context, not the inner one.

Within xslt, I have also tried to use keys as such:

```xml
<xsl:key name="dept_number_key" match="/data/items/item" use="dept_number"/>
<xsl:for-each select="/data/items/item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dept_number_key', dept_number)[1]) and position() $gt; $min-pos and position() &lt;= $max-pos]">
</xsl:for-each>
```

but this still does not work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit: The range I am referring to is not a range of dept_number values, but a range of `<item>` tags within `<items>`. For instance, if the range was 3 to 5 I would want to get back the third, fourth and fifth `<item>` tag within `<items>`.**

Comment: Can you explain in plain English what you want to achieve if you say "return a node set of items within a certain range which have distinct dept_number values within them"? Is the range about the value of the items? The key you have set up would allow to select the first unique item of every value in the, perhaps you just want your positional predicate added to that: `/data/items/item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dept_number_key', dept_number)[1])][position() &gt; $min-pos and position() &lt;= $max-pos]`.

Comment: Apologises for the lack of clarity. The range in this case is simply referring to the position of the items within the parent node. So if I have an `<items>` tag and ten `<item>` tags within it, and a range from 3 to 5, I want to get back the third, fourth and fifth `<item>` tag within `<items>`. I hope that helps to clear things up a bit. When I use that query that uses the key I get the error `Line #178; Column #185; Expected ], but found: $`

Comment: Well, you have `$gt;` instead of `&gt;`. But I am not sure that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that mistake out. I was very confused as to why that error was appearing. Unfortunately, you are right, that doesn't solve my problem. The query does return distinct values within the given range, but not the first distinct value if that value is also present in an `<item>` tag before the start of the range. For instance, if the range goes from 5 to 8, and `<item>` 5 has a value of `014`, but so does `<item>` 4, the query will not return `<item>` 5, even though this has a distinct `dept_number` _within_ the range.

Comment: Ideally, I would define the key's match attribute dynamically, but I don't believe this is possible because I have an unknown amount of ranges and the key has to be defined in the top level of the xsl file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***--- edited in response to clarification ---***

I would start by copying the items in range to a new "document", so that you can later use Muenchian grouping on them to get only distinct values. Without this, the grouping can fail if, for example, item #3 is not the first item with the given `dept_number`value.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT node-set() function**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="min-pos" select="3" />
<xsl:variable name="max-pos" select="5" />

<xsl:key name="dept_number_key" match="item" use="dept_number" />

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:variable name="items-in-range">
        <xsl:copy-of select="items/item[$min-pos &lt;= position() and position() &lt;= $max-pos]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($items-in-range)/item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('dept_number_key', dept_number)[1])]/dept_number"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that some XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT `set:distinct()` extension function. This could shorten the code here.

Comment: I don't think I outlined my question as clearly as I could have. The range I'm talking about is not a range of dept_number values, but a range of `<item>` tags within the `<items>` tag. So a range of 3 to 5 would return the third, fourth and fifth `<item>` tags within `<items>`.

Comment: It looks like the use of `key` here still operates in the context of the original document, not in the context of the node-set. If you set `min-pos` to 4, then it does not return the dept_number of "2" in the results.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.